# How to Play High Quality Video in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using `MovieTexture` now, but when a video file is added to unity Project, it will automatically be imported and converted to Ogg Theora format. and the quality is really bad.

I have tried changing the quality setting and even on the highest setting the video is still pretty bad quality, I have tried it in multiple file formats like .mov, .avi. .mpeg4 etc. I have even tried converting it to .ogv to try and get around unity converting it itself, and still the quality is poor. The platform is PC, and in the build the quality is the same as in the editor.

so the question is ,how to play high quality video in unity no matter using `MovieTexture` or anything else like some plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity player on Windows only supports OGG, which is why Unity is transcoding your videos.

I have use the Renderheads AVPRo Quicktime plugin on Windows to play very high quality videos in kiosk setups. (They also have one for Windows Media format, but I used Quicktime).

Link: [Renderheads AVPro (Quicktime)](http://www.renderheads.com/portfolio/UnityAVProQuickTime/)

I am not affiliated with them in any way, just a very happy customer, and here is the review I posted on the Unity Asset store:

> Great work on your plugin! I've used so many plugins that don't work well over multiple platforms, or require switching between platforms, or manual steps, or manual licensing, or DLL hell, etc. I have to say you nailed it.
>
> I develop on a Mac (and your plugin runs in the Unity Editor), then deploying on Windows. It all worked well straight forward and as documented. Even the events to detect when a video has loaded and is ready to play just what I needed (as we are loading a large video file).
>
> Additionally, the error messages are very precise and pin-point a problem (missing file, bad format, etc) which means less time debugging.

Comment: ffmpeg is always a good swiss knife in these situations.